# How to communicate from BroadcastReceiver to Activity after instantiating repeating alarm

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-intent, alarmmanager

I am creating a recurring alarm, which I want to be able to communicate with the `Activity` that called it.  I can send `Intent` data over to the `BroadcastReceiver` but getting information back from the `Activity` at the time the `BroadcastReceiver` runs is not immediately clear. I need the `BroadcastReceiver` to poll information from the `Activity` that called it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am creating a recurring alarm, which I want to be able to communicate with the Activity that called it.

It is rather likely that "the Activity that called it" no longer exists, because it has been destroyed.

> I need the BroadcastReceiver to poll information from the Activity that called it.

No, you don't. You need your `Activity` and your `BroadcastReceiver` to use a shared persistent data model, such as a database or file, possibly cached via static data members.

Comment: I ended up using reflection to pass a `String` of the qualified class name that implements an `interface` so that I can call `invokeMethod` to call the method passed through the `Intent`.  Although its not the `Activity` that called it, turns out to be easier than the persistent storage. +1 No `Activity` to `BroadcastReceiver`